# Play framework 2.0 - deadLetters instead of an Actor

Tags: scala, akka, playframework-2.0

For learning purposes I'm trying to implement a simple play application that gets data from a remote actor. The code for the actor is as follows:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem, Actor}

class NumbersServer extends Actor {
  var number = 0
  protected def receive = {
    case 'next => {
      number += 1
      number
    }
    case 'reset => number = 0
    case 'exit => context.stop(self)
    case 'get => sender ! number
  }
}

object Server {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("ServerSystem")
    val server = system.actorOf(Props[NumbersServer], "server")
  }
}
```

I package it into a jar and start it from the command line. If I try to send messages to this actor from a Scala console opened from another window, all works fine. Now I want to get the actor from the Play framework. In the `Application` object I define the following method:

```
def numbers = Action {
  Ok(views.html.numbers(Client.actor.path.name))
}
```

Then in the `models` package I define the Client object:

```
object Client {
  import play.api.Play.current
  val actor = Akka.system.actorFor("akka://ServerSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/server")
}
```

The `numbers.html.scala` file:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Header") {
    <h1>@message</h1>
}
```

So I expect that when I go to `127.0.0.1:9000/numbers`, I'd get a page with the path to the server actor. Instead of this, I get `<h1>deadLetters</h1>`. What do I do wrong and how this should be done correctly?

Comment: Have you've enabled remoting on both ends?

Comment: @ViktorKlang : I tried to enable remoting in play in a way analogous to plain akka, but there is no akka-remote package, so I just got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider` and not sure what else to do.

Comment: Akka docs are rather good: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/remoting.html

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand something. I read those manuals, found them very useful, and in fact remoting works just fine when I do it in a plain akka application. But how do I enable akka remoting under the play framework? Is it enough to add the akka-remote dependency to sbt configuration of a play app and write the same config file as in plain akka?

Comment: You'll need to ask the Play! team about that, they ship a reference.conf file with Play! 2: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf I assume that such things are documented in the Play! 2 docs. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the configuration given in

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/Vw-B8nQeagk

And also add akka-remote dependency

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote" % "2.0.2"
)
```